# Alicloud SQL-Hive, SQL to exclude number only and alphabet only and single chinese word only

Tags: sql, hive, where-clause, hiveql

I have a column like below

```
**col1**
1244
a888d
ahahd
我
我是
19mon
```

The output I would like to have is

```
**col1**
a888d
我是
19mon
```

I was trying to use syntax below to exclude number only and alphabet only, however no strings were printed out. And I don't know how to exclude single chinese word, like"我" above.

```
SELECT col1 from abc
where col1 like '%[^0-9.]%' AND col1 like '%[^a-zA-Z.]%'
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex:

```
with your_data as (
select stack(6,
'1244',
'a888d',
'ahahd',
'我',
'我是',
'19mon'
) as col1
) 

select col1 from your_data
 where col1 not rlike ('^\\d+$')      --not digits only
   and col1 not rlike ('^[a-zA-Z]+$') --not alpha only
   and length(col1) !=1;              --not single char (digit and alpha filtered already)
```

Returns:

```
col1    
a888d   
我是  
19mon
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is very efficient solution.  I just wonder why we need to use one more backlash before \d?

Comment: @ZedFang This is documented: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF Look for regexp_extract, there is an explanation

Comment: @ZedFang The thing is \ is used as escape character in Hive. And \d means digit. Need to escape \ one more time because single slash will be interpreted in Hive as escape character.

Comment: got it. Just do some research, \\d will mean \d in mysql, as hive is coded by java. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM abc
WHERE LOWER(col1) != UPPER(col1) -- COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS SQL Server specific
  OR (LENGTH(col1) != 1 AND col1 like '%[^a-zA-Z.0-9]%');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1ae36b80d0cbeb804d3407a7a72a72e2)**

Comment: I am not aware that Hive supports that `LIKE` pattern.